# Kubernates pass env variable to "kubectl create"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to pass dynamic env variable to `kubectl create`.  Something like this

`kubectl create -f app.yaml --Target=prod`

Based on Target code deploys on different servers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to avoid installing 3rd party plugin then you can replace the text using sed "s/orginal/change/". It worked. I used this in Jenkins shell.

**cat app.yaml | sed "s/l3-apps/l2-apps/" | kubectl create -f -**

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in two ways:

1. Use [Helm](https://helm.sh/). It is a "package manager" for Kubernetes and is built exactly for your use case (dynamic variables to configure behaviour of your resources). If it is only a single variable, "converting" your deployment is as simple as creating a new Helm chart, copy your files into `templates/`, modify `values.yaml` and use `{{ .Values.target }}` in your templates. See the [quickstart guide](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#quickstart) for a more in-depth introduction to Helm.
2. If you consider Helm to be over the top for a single variable, use `kubectl`'s capability to read from standard input. You'll need an additional templating tool (for example [mustache](https://github.com/mustache/mustache)). Rewrite your deployment to fit your templating tool. Create a dynamic `data.yml` in your deployment process (e.g. a simple bash script that reads from environment variables) and run something like `mustache data.yml deployment.mustache | kubectl apply -f -`.

Answer (score 1):

kubectl config set-context allows you to configure cluster, namespace, user credentials and more and save it as a "context" in your ~/.kube/config.

The you can use --context option of kubectl exactly in a way that you used --Target in your example.

Comment: After reading the question again, this seems to be the better answer. I missunderstood the intention.

Comment: Thanks. But I can only change available options.

Answer (score 0):

I've published a command-line tool [ysed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ysed) that also performs what you need.