# How can I manually set values on a Kubernetes object using kubectl create?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In particular, I want to set environment variables. I have a `CronJob` definition that runs on a schedule, but every so often I want to invoke it manually while specifying slightly different environment variables.

I can invoke the cron job manually with this command:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/my-cron-job my-manual-run
```

But that copies in all the same environment variables that are specified in the resource definition. How can I add additional, new environment variables using this `create job` command?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50297738/10675601

Comment: That other question you linked had two answers: (1) use Helm, or (2) input the entire resource definition YAML. So in other words... it sounds like there isn't really a solution to my specific question.

Comment: Or rather, the answer is "no you can't do that, not directly."

Comment: Haha! I guess; they are workarounds that can wrapped into one-liners that I thought might suite your purpose.

Comment: I think you should probably stop using `kubectl create` and use YAML manifests and edit them, then `kubectl apply -f` them at this point. Imperative commands go only so far...

Comment: Can you give an example of how you invoke it differently? Based on your question alone, it's not clear if you're editing "my-cron-job", or if you're changing the value of the environment variables.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson that's just the thing: I don't know the right parameters (if they exist) to invoke it differently... that's what I'm trying to find out. But here's a pseudo-command to illustrate what I'm trying to do: `kubectl create job --from=cronjob/my-cron-job --set ".spec.metadata.env.DRY_RUN=1" my-manual-run`. Here that `--set` flag is an entirely made-up flag, representing manually overriding some part of the spec. But I'm not sure if such a flag really does exist.

Comment: I don't think that's possible via parameters to this command. You could set them manually on the node(s)/host you're deploying to. Or write a script to do it.

Answer (score 8):

I built on the answer from @Rico to first create the job in kubectl as a `--dry-run`, then modifiy the job using `jq`, then apply. This removes the need for having base JSON files and having to manage additional job metadata fields.

For example:

```sh
$ kubectl create job --from=cronjob/my-cron-job my-manual-run --dry-run -o "json" \
  | jq ".spec.template.spec.containers[0].env += [{ \"name\": \"envname1\", value:\"$envvalue1\" }]" \
  | kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest to do IMO is to have a base JSON file and modify it. The output of `kubectl get cronjob jobname` has a lot of other info that you don't need.

For example:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "batch/v1",
    "kind": "Job",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "changeme"
    },
    "spec": {
        "template": {
            "metadata": {
                "labels": {
                    "job-name": "changeme"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "restartPolicy": "Never",
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "command": [
                            "perl",
                            "-Mbignum=bpi",
                            "-wle",
                            "print bpi(2000)"
                        ],
                        "image": "perl",
                        "name": "pi"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then run something like this:

```
$ cat yourjobtemplate.json \
  | jq '. + {metadata: {name: "mynewjobname"}}' \
  | jq '.spec.template.metadata.labels |= . + {"job-name": "mynewjobname"}' \
  | jq '.spec.template.spec.containers[0] |= . + {"env": [{name: "envname1", value: "envvalue1"}, {name: "envname2", value: "envvalue2"}]}' \
  | kubectl apply -f -
```